# Combine for loop with while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, hex

i'm trying to write a python script that will find `X` what i mean is

```
x & 0xe = 0x6
```

i want to find all of the combinations that can give me the hex result of `x & 0xe = 0x6`

so the first thing iv'e done is creating a script that test if `x & 0xe = 0x6` so i can find some `X` combinations

```
GetStr=(raw_input('1st Hex:'))
GetStr2=hex(0xe)

StrToHex=int(GetStr,16)
StrToHex2=int(GetStr2,16)
cal = (hex(StrToHex & StrToHex2))

while cal != hex(0x6):
    print "no"
    GetStr = (raw_input('1st Hex:'))
    GetStr2 = hex(0xe)

    StrToHex = int(GetStr, 16)
    StrToHex2 = int(GetStr2, 16)
    cal = (hex(StrToHex & StrToHex2))
else:
    print GetStr
```

The second script is a for loop that will create all combinations that will be tested in the while loop

```
GetStr=(raw_input('1st Hex:'))
StrToHex = int(GetStr, 16)

GetStr2=hex(0x100)
StrToHex2=int(GetStr2,16)

for i in range(StrToHex,StrToHex2,1):
    print hex(i)
```

The thing is i find it hard to make it work the way i want it, all it needs to do is to find all combinations that could sum to `0x6` and print it.

Thanks!

Comment: There are infinitely many `x` that satisfy this equation. Just start with `x` as `0x6` and keep adding bits that are not present in `0xe`

Answer (score 1):

First, note that it is impossible to find all the values of `x` such that `x & 0xe == 0x6`, because there are infinitely many of them. `bin(0x6)` is `'0b110'` and `bin(0xe)` is `'0b1110'`, so every number that has all the bits that are in both numbers and *any other bits* that are not also in `0xe` will be a solution.

About your code: Not entirely clear what you are asking. As I understand the question, you want to transform the manual method from the first snippet to a loop automatically testing all the numbers in a certain range. For this, I suggest making a function for the `check` that you can reuse in both loops, and also defining some variables for the other two values. Also, currently you are constantly converting from `int` to `hex`-string and back to `int`. Just work with `int` all the time and just convert to `hex` for printing.

You can try something like this:

```
# function used in both loops
def check(first, second, target):
    return first & second == target

# manual loop with user input
second, target = 0xe, 0x6
print("find solution for x & 0x%x = 0x%x" % (second, target))
while True:
    first = int(raw_input('1st hex: '), 16)
    if check(first, second, target):
        print("yes")
        break
    else:
        print("no")
```

Or even shorter (but probably not as readable):

```
while not check(int(raw_input('1st hex: '), 16), second, target):
    print("no")
print("yes")
```

Then, just call that function in your `for` loop.

```
# automated loop testing values in range
upper = 0x100
for n in range(upper):
    if check(n, second, target):
        print(hex(n))
```